# Inground trashcan hinge

Tags: concrete, construction, underground, trash-can

I am trying to search for the in ground trashcan hinge. I've tried searching online for the part but don't know the correct name of it. Very hard to come by locally. The lid where it attached is about 4 inches wide. It has a spring so it doesn't remain open. I may have to engineer one myself since I don't have the cement ring shown in the following picture, but not sure what parts to get.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Is that strap or hinge aluminum? , it may be easier to purchase a piece of bar stock of similar material and size then form it to match the good one. I have made brackets using the following technique. A hammer vice and screw, bolt or something the approximate size to roll the end, start by clamping the bar stock in the vice fold over this gives a L shape make sure the L will be long enough to make the loop. keep working the fold over by putting just bar stock in the vice and rest the folded piece on the bolt now pound down on the L folded piece down and you have a u shape. Put the U in the vice with the bolt above the jaws and close this makes the loop for the hinge rod. Now shape to match the original. Drill holes as needed to mount.
I have tried starting at the end and trying to clamp the rod and bar together and rolling , readjusting, rolling but on thicker stock have found making the L and working from there was easier. Most big box stores have bar stock that can be used for this repair and even a lighter weight steel strap could be used if this is aluminum.

Comment: The lazy man would go to an auto junkyard and procure a leaf spring with eyelets already formed. A bit of cutting and shimming (to reduce the size of the eyelet), and you're done.